# Excel VBA Bit Control

Tags: excel, vba, binary, binaryfiles, bit

In Excel VBA I'm messing around with reading and writing binary files.

I was wondering if it is possible to instead of only changing the bytes to actually work with the bits. I don't mean taking each byte and converting it to 8 bits, I mean if it is possible to create/modify/read files with bit control where it might be, for example, a file with only 4 bits, or 10, instead of always being multiple of 8.

Here's some of the code that I'm using:

```
Private Sub WriteFile()
  Dim path As String, num As Byte, arr(2) As Byte
  path = "test.bin"
  arr(0) = CByte(&HA1)
  arr(1) = CByte(&HC4)
  arr(2) = CByte(&HA1)
  num = FreeFile
  If Dir(path) <> "" Then Kill path
  Open path For Binary Access Write As num
  Put num, , arr
  Close num
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the question is why would you do that? I think since the smallest I/O unit of a file is 1 byte (8 bits) you will always need to write 1 full byte.

The approach would be to generate a bit stream and convert that into bytes (just before writing the file).

So the approach to change one bit would be read 1 full byte change the bit in that byte and write 1 full byte back to the file.

You won't save any space on disk anyway because you always need to write 1 full sector to the disk and typically 1 sector = 512 bytes. So any file below 512 bytes will always use the full 512 bytes on the disk.

Comment: If that is correct than that answers my question. I know bits don't make any real difference I was just wondering if it was possible or not since the smallest unit being worked on in all binary editors I see are always with bytes in hexadecimal or something like that. And even when I check a file's size it's always bytes the smaller unit. Just wanted to know out of curiosity if I could have a file with 1 bit instead of 1 byte. Thanks.

Comment: To answer that question "*… have a file with 1 bit instead of 1 byte*": No, you can't.